# How to redirect to another localhost when "Unable to connect Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ''some ip

Tags: php, android, apache, network-programming

I have created a webservice with php for my android application, in the header of the php I have given the code

```
header("Location: http://123.123.123.123/Main/sub.php?details=".$rawdata);
```

Please note that this is a closed network ip, this ip can only be accessed from the same network so when I change the WIFI network to another, I need to change the above code as

```
header("Location: http://123.123.123.124/Main/sub.php?details=".$rawdata);
```

If dont change it I will get the error message as   `"Unable to connect  Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 123.123.123.123"`

What I want is that when I switch network from A to B, instead of the above error page I want the page to be redirected to the location specified in the second code. Somebody please help

I am using apache2 in ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by putting simple check for checking weather host is accessible or not.

```
  $host = 'http://123.123.123.123';

    // Number of seconds to wait for a response from remote host
    $timeout = 2;

    // TCP port to connect to
    $port = 80;
    // Try and connect
    if ($sock = fsockopen($host, $port, $errNo, $errStr, $timeout)) {
        // Connected successfully
        $up = TRUE;
        fclose($sock); // Drop connection immediately for tidiness
    } else {
        // Connection failed
        $up = FALSE;
    }
   if ($up) {
      header("Location: http://123.123.123.123/Main/sub.php?details=".$rawdata);
   }
   else {
       header("Location: http://123.123.123.124/Main/sub.php?details=".$rawdata);
   }
```

by this check you can easily redirect the location accordingly. you can change the timeout as per your script execution time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` to determine IP address of the client. This should let you perform the redirect as needed. `ip2long` is quite useful in this context, e.g.:

```
if ((ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) & 0xffffff00) == ip2long('123.123.123.0')) {
   header("Location: http://123.123.123.124/Main/sub.php?details=".$rawdata);
} else {
   header("Location: http://123.123.123.123/Main/sub.php?details=".$rawdata);
}
```

`ip2long` converts the IP address from dotted notation into `long`. This will let you perform bitwise operations which make subnet matching very straight-forward.

Of course I'd suggest you avoid hardcoding any IP ranges or addresses into your code. Have them stored in a database or somewhere else where they can be easily maintained when things changes.